# Linear transformations that preserve permutations of a vector.

Tags: permutations, transformation

Forgive me if this question sounds silly.

Let $v$ be a $m \times 1$ vector and $P$ be a $m \times m$ permutation matrix. Can there be a transformation $T$ such that $\min_\limits{P\neq I}\|Tv-TPv\|$ exists?

Is this only a computational problem or are there analytic ideas about this problem, like invariant sets, etc.? Thanks!

Comment: Is the identity matrix considered a permutation matrix?

Comment: Sorry, changed it. No, identity excluded.

Comment: What is an $m \times n$ vector?  Do you mean an $m \times 1$ vector?

Comment: Oops! Yes. Again, sorry.

Comment: So, certainly this minimum exists for any choice of $T$ and $v$, since there are only finitely many permutations to consider. Is there something we're missing here?  Is this a minimum over some set of vectors?

Comment: What do you want T to look like?  Does T have to be invertible?  Because $T=0$ will always be minimum for the norm.

Comment: Well, it will reduce to more equations than unknowns as the permutations are exponential and the entries in the matrices are only $m^2$. An optimal solution is likely to be there although computationally expensive. I am trying to see if there is any body of literature that deals with such problems like in math physics.

Comment: Of course, better to have T invertible. I am trying to see from a physics perspective where entries could be transformed so that they  are independent of coordinates and so permuting them will not change them in the transformed space.